# SQL Server TSQL - How to achieve "NOT IN" statements within a CASE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have the following working code:

```
    INSERT INTO #resultado

    SELECT  1,

        v.idReqVoucher,
        v.dtSolicitacao,
        v.idFuncionario_solicitante,
        v.idFuncionario_beneficiario,
        v.idStatus,         
        NULL as valor
    FROM reqVoucher v
    WHERE
         v.idReqVoucher =  
            CASE WHEN @idRequisicao = 0 THEN v.idReqVoucher
            ELSE @idRequisicao END
        AND v.idStatus =  
            CASE WHEN @status = 0 THEN v.idStatus
            ELSE @status END

        AND v.dtSolicitacao >= CASE WHEN @dtSolicitacaoIni IS NULL THEN v.dtSolicitacao ELSE  @dtSolicitacaoIni END
        AND v.dtSolicitacao <= CASE WHEN @dtSolicitacaoFim IS NULL THEN v.dtSolicitacao ELSE  @dtSolicitacaoFim+' 23:59:59' END
```

But what I need to achieve is something like that:

```
AND v.idStatus  
CASE WHEN @status = 99 THEN NOT IN (5,1,4,20)
ELSE WHEN @status != 0 THEN = @status END
```

And I have no idea on how achieve that in my code. I'm fairly new in TSQL and SQL Server, so please be gentle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CASE statement returns a value, it does not act as an IF statement by changing the SQL query (if this, then do that). You would need to modify your where statement to something like the following:

```
AND (
       (@status = 99 AND v.idStatus NOT IN (5, 1, 4, 20))
       OR (@status NOT IN (0, 99) AND v.idStatus = @status)
     )
```

Edit: Commenter is correct, the 2nd check needs to ensure the @status is not 99.

Comment: If `@status = 99` *and* `v.idStatus = 99` then the above will evaluate to `true`, which contradicts the result of the `CASE` pseudocode cited in the OP.

Answer (score 2):

Or use a `CASE` *expression*:

```
and case
  when @status = 99 and v.idStatus not in ( 5, 1, 4, 20 ) then 1
  when @status !=0 and v.idStatus = @status then 1
  else 0
  end = 1
```

The `CASE` expression returns a value which you must then use, e.g. by comparing it to `1`. It is generally good practice to include an `ELSE` clause to supply a default value should the unexpected arise.

Answer (score 1):

This should be equivalent to what you want:

```
 AND (
      (@status = 99) AND (v.idStatus NOT IN (5,1,4,20))
      OR
      (@status <> 99) AND (@status <> 0) AND (v.idStatus = @status)
     )
```

`CASE` expression can only be used to return a scalar value, so it cannot be used to return a predicate like `NOT IN (5,1,4,20)`.

Comment: Hello there. Thanks for the quick response.

I'm getting the following errors:

    Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure sp_buscaTodasRequisicoes, Line 180
    Incorrect syntax near ')'.
    Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure sp_buscaTodasRequisicoes, Line 1106
    Incorrect syntax near 'END'

EDIT: My break lines are not showing in response field, weird.

Comment: @BrunoAlbuquerque Parenthesis matching error. Please check the edit I made.